# calculate year-to-date in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to create a row with the year-to-date value of each year-month column.

My data starts at "202101" and each time a new column is created, such as this month *(which would be the "202403" column).*
But I will only represent a piece of the dataframe.

| id | 202101 | 202102 | 202103 | 202104 | 202105 | ... | 202201 | 202202 | 202203 | 202204 | 202102 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 101 | 104.4 | 104 | 95 | ... | 45 | 38 | 102 | 150 | 120 |

I want to create the year-to-date calculation in the line with id 3 (as 2 already has another calculation)

**year-to-date formula for 202201:**
202201 value in `id 1`: 45 divided by 202101 value in `id 1`: 100 minus 1

- 45/100-1 = -0.55

**year-to-date formula for 202202:**
(202201 value in `id 1`: 45 plus 202202 value in `id 1`: 38 divided by (202101 value in `id 1`: 100 plus 202102 value in `id 1`: 101) minus 1

- (45+38)/(100+101)-1 = -0.587

**year-to-date formula for 202203:**

- (45+38+102)/(100+101+104.4)-1 = -0.394

And add the results of each calculation to the reference year-month

| id | 202101 | 202102 | 202103 | 202104 | 202105 | ... | 202201 | 202202 | 202203 | 202204 | 202205 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 101 | 104.4 | 104 | 95 | ... | 45 | 38 | 102 | 150 | 120 |
| 2 | x | x | x | x | x | ... | x | x | x | x | x |
| 3 | - | - | - | - | - | ... | -0.55 | -0.587 | -0.394 | -0.182 | -0.098 |

Code:

```
data = [(1, 100, 101, 101.4, 104, 95, 85, 89, 111, 120, 75, 100, 20, 45, 38, 102, 150, 120, 180, 50, 98, 105, 120)]


columns = ["id", "202101", "202102", "202103", "202104", "202105", "202106", "202107", "202108", "202109", "202111", "202112", "202201", "202202", "202203", "202204", "202205", "202206", "202207", "202208", "202209", "202211", "202212"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)
```